# pyserial readline() times out after reconnection

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, 3d-printing

I use pyserial to communicate with a 3D printer (Monoprice Select Mini V2) via USB. Everything works well when I connect to the printer for the first time, but when I try to reopen a connection I can still send commands but do not receive any character.

This happens when I close the port and reopen it in the same program or when I rerun for the second time a python script opening the port after the first script has returned. The only way to reconnect properly is to restart my printer or to unplug and replug it. Changing the timeout value or trying to read only one byte does not solve the problem.

Short nonworking example:

```py
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=115200, timeout=5)
ser.write("\n".encode())
print(ser.readline().decode())
# prints 'echo:Unknown command: "~"' (Not sure why)
print(ser.readline().decode())
# prints 'ok N0 P15 B15'
ser.write("M105\n".encode())
# prints expected response
ser.close()
print(ser.isOpen())
# prints 'False'

ser.open()
print(ser.isOpen())
# prints 'True'
ser.write("\n".encode())
print(ser.readline().decode())
# times out
ser.write("M105\n".encode())
print(ser.readline().decode())
# times out
```

Comment: Is the port actually open after opening it for the second time? Try `print(ser.isOpen())`.

Comment: @bromosapien Yes, I updated the question to show that.